# Python Selenium setting path to firefox profile in ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have set the path to a newly created Firefox profile in Ubuntu using python & Selenium. But when I run the python script I am getting this problem

```
/bin/python3 /home/frixreda/Desktop/Python/testU.py
/home/frixreda/Desktop/Python/testU.py:7: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
/home/frixreda/Desktop/Python/testU.py:13: DeprecationWarning: capabilities and desired_capabilities have been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
/home/frixreda/Desktop/Python/testU.py:13: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
```

This is my python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
       r'/home/frixreda/.mozilla/firefox/3uz1obam.default')
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
                     desired_capabilities=desired)

driver.get("https://gmail.com/")
```

Comment: you have all in error message: `DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object`. So you should use `Options()`  instead of `FirefoxProfile()`. Or maybe rather `FirefoxOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

`Browsers` are changing and `Selenium` also changes some settings - and now old methods are deprecated but still can work (it was only warning, not error).

But warning shows that preferred method is to use `Option()` instead of `FirefoxProfile()`

And it doesn't need to use `DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX` which adds

```
{'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True}
```

because it has it automatically in `options.capabilities`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
#from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = Options()

#help(options)

options.add_argument('-profile')
options.add_argument('/home/frixreda/.mozilla/firefox/3uz1obam.default')

options.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
options.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)

#options.set_headless()  # deprecated
#options.headless = True # preferred

#options.set_capability(name, value)
#print("DesiredCapabilities:", DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)  # {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True}

print('accept_insecure_certs:', options.accept_insecure_certs)
print('arguments   :', options.arguments)
print('preferences :', options.preferences)
print('capabilities:', options.capabilities)
print('headless    :', options.headless)
print('profile     :', options.profile)  # `None`??? but browser uses profile
print('proxy       :', options.proxy)
print('binary      :', options.binary)
#print('binary_location:', options.binary_location)
print('log         :', options.log)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

#driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
driver.get("https://gmail.com")
```

---

**BTW:** you can use `help(options)` to see all options with descriptions.

Comment: `dom.webdriver.enabled` is ignored by Firefox 88 or newer.